# An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Buenas a tod@s, estoy creando una plantilla para appium y me está dando problemas en los webElements. El driver si me lo pilla porque me carga la pantalla y la pagina donde quiero ir para usar esa prueba, pero a la hora de llamar un webElement me dice **An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.** Cuando en realidad si lo pilla. Estoy con appium 1.5.1 y selenium 3.141.59 y de appium 7.0.0.
Este el es código:

PO:

```
public class InicioPageObject{
    protected AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='jss27']")
    public WebElement cookies2;
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//button[@id='rcc-confirm-button']")
    public WebElement cookies;
    
    

    public InicioPageObject(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driverMobile) {
        this.driver = driverMobile;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    public void addData() {
        System.out.println("driver "+driver);
        try {
            driver.navigate().to("http://pagina.com");
            Thread.sleep(3000); 
        
    
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          } }
```

Test:

```
@Test(groups = {"calculadora","open"})// we add the tags that we want to add it
public class InicioTest extends BaseContext{
    
    InicioPageObject home;
    
 
    
    @Test
    public void openCalculator() throws InterruptedException {
         home = new InicioPageObject(driver); // Inicializa aquí
        System.out.println("que es "+driver);
        //driverMobile.navigate().to("http://innocv.com");
        home.addData();
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='rcc-confirm-button']"));
        element.click();
    }

}
```

Aquí donde me falla, tanto si lo pongo en el PO como en la ejecución de test.

```
public class BaseContext extends MobileConfiguration implements TestSetup{
...... codigo de ejecución........ protected static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    
    public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> connectAppiumAndroid() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "4b22821f9806");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "10");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.chrome");//com.android.chrome  com.miui.calculator
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");    // com.miui.calculator.cal.CalculatorActivity

        
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        return (AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver;

    }...}
```

Error entero : An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'MacBook-Pro-de-Administrator-2.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14aa:d6b1:e141%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.5.1', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {appActivity: com.google.android.apps.chr..., appPackage: com.android.chrome, browserName: , databaseEnabled: false, desired: {appActivity: com.google.android.apps.chr..., appPackage: com.android.chrome, browserName: , device: Android, deviceName: 4b22821f9806, platformName: android, platformVersion: 10}, device: Android, deviceApiLevel: 29, deviceManufacturer: Xiaomi, deviceModel: Redmi 7A, deviceName: 4b22821f9806, deviceScreenDensity: 320, deviceScreenSize: 720x1440, deviceUDID: 4b22821f9806, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, pixelRatio: 2, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 10, statBarHeight: 55, takesScreenshot: true, viewportRect: {height: 1289, left: 0, top: 55, width: 720}, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: a06ed3f8-ded9-44da-856c-06ea20115698
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//button[@id='rcc-confirm-button']}